# rails tutorial ch 2 error noMethodError: undefined method 'micropost'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I am a new RoR and am completing the railstutorial: Chapter 2.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, virtualized with  with Sublime Text 2.  I am using Terminal as my command prompt.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

I have had a few trials and errors but right now I am stumped and stuck.

I am working on the Demo_app and am stuck at figure 2.3.3
I've tested my localhost:3000 and both the /users/ and /microposts/ pages have been generated and everything works functionally.  i.e. new, edit, destroy, etc.

I had done both the user and the micropost rakes, the 'bundle exec rake db:migrate', to apparently update the data model.

I now am entering the ruby console by typing 'ruby console' in terminal
upon completion I get 
    1.9.1 :001 > 
        first_user = User.first , the response is, 
           User Load (0.1ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1

=> #

I now get

```
 1.9.1 :002 > and I type first_user.microposts
```

This is the resulting error I get with included command

```
1.9.1 :001 > first_user = User.first
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "User Name", email: "example@example.com", created_at: "2013-06-23 23:17:01", updated_at: "2013-06-23 23:17:01"> 
1.9.1 :002 > first_user.microposts
NoMethodError: undefined method `microposts' for #<User:0xa6e8afc>
    from /home/user/rails_projects/demo_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    from /home/user/rails_projects/demo_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):2
    from /home/user/rails_projects/demo_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/user/rails_projects/demo_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/user/rails_projects/demo_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I guess I will also post the other files I thought might be involved with the error.

my micropost.rb

```
    class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :user_id

   belongs_to :user

   validates :content, :length => { :maximum => 140 }
   end
```

my users_controller.rb

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      # GET /users
      # GET /users.json
      def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
     end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
     if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
       format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
     end
  end
end
```

My user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :name
    has_many :microposts
end
```

My index.html.erb file

```
  </tr>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you     sure?'     } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

my routes.rb

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :microposts


  resources :users

#...
end
```

and I guess my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

The only complication I have ran into that I know of is when going through the tutorial is on 2.1 where you use the command

bundle update

and then

bundle install --without production

I had to reverse this process for the update to work properly...  I looked on stackoverflow and found some other work arounds... perhaps it is this or  somehow the way in which I setup my server or the original gems, ruby, rails install.

Thank you for your help, If I didn't post this correctly, I will take suggestions.

Tkin1

Comment: go to project root, and restart the console. everything seems fine, Just make sure to start console you have to use `rails console ` Or `Rails c`

Comment: unfortunately I have tried doing that and closing the console with cntrl d.  I also have deleted the repo re scaffolded and launched the server again a few times now.  

perhaps you have another suggestion to help locate the root of the problem?

Comment: can you share your code repo?

Comment: yes one moment, let me make this commit.

Comment: https://github.com/tkinetik1/demo_app.git

Answer (score 7):

your User model look like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
end
```

No association is defined. Make it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_many: :microposts
end
```

You mentioned it in your post , but it does not reflect your code

Comment: ok perhaps I have in this latest deployment as  I tried to fix the errors, I will try this and let you know. one moment...

Comment: Yes!  I am very excited.  What I wasn't doing was saving in Sublime Text but instead closing the editor.  I think this will solve a hand full of my problems.  Thank you,  I would vote this up if I had the reputation, perhaps someone else will.

Comment: I'll +1 it on your behalf :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was that I had started `rails console` without saving `user.rb` or `micropost.rb`.

I resolved it by exiting `rails console`, saving both model files, and restarting `rails console`.

It was not sufficient to save the model files without restarting `rails console`.

Comment: hah,  for me I just had to ctrl-c out of the rail console and restart the rail console.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error and here is what fixed it: 
Don't follow the book when entering associations, instead type

```
has_many :Micropost
```

and

```
belongs_to: User
```

Note both 'Micropost' and 'User' are **capitalized** and 'Micropost' is **singular** not plural

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have the answer by now but what I found my problem was, was this.

I didn't run the second `bundle exec rake db:migrate` when I did that it fixed the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix my issue.

1) Double check your micropost.rb and user.rb.

> I had a spelling issue here that needed to be corrected.

2) Delete your old posts, create new

> If you created records with the old configuration, I think that causes issues. i deleted my posts (using the application) and then created a few new ones for user 1. After this, I was able to run the rails console commands.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart the rails miniserver by running `rails server` again.